# Opening response from urllib2.urlopen() on the fly with zipfile.ZipFile

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

It seems `zipfile.ZipFile` requires random access which is is not supported by `urllib2`'s returned "file-like" object.

I've tried wrapping it with `io.BufferedRandom` but got:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'seekable'
```

Comment: Can you show more code as to how you use `urlopen` and pass it into `ZipFile` or the buffer, please?

Comment: ```resp = urllib2.urlopen(url)
ios = io.BufferedRandom(resp)
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(ios)
...```
Please note that I'm trying to avoid reading all the content at once with `StringIO(resp.read())` (which works fine).

Answer (score 1):

In absence of other responses I've settled down with a home-made solution below. It probably won't reduce *memory* footprint when reading zip files yet it might improve latency when `zip` header is read first.

````
from io import BytesIO, SEEK_SET, SEEK_END

def _ceil_div(a, b):
    return (a + b - 1) / b

def _align_up(a, b):
    return _ceil_div(a, b) * b

class BufferedRandomReader:
    """Create random-access, read-only buffered stream adapter from a sequential
    input stream which does not support random access (i.e., ```seek()```)

    Example::

        >>> stream = BufferedRandomReader(BytesIO('abc'))
        >>> print stream.read(2)
        ab
        >>> stream.seek(0)
        0L
        >>> print stream.read()
        abc

    """

    def __init__(self, fin, chunk_size=512):
        self._fin = fin
        self._buf = BytesIO()
        self._eof = False
        self._chunk_size = chunk_size

    def tell(self):
        return self._buf.tell()

    def read(self, n=-1):
        """Read at most ``n`` bytes from the file (less if the ```read``` hits
        end-of-file before obtaining size bytes).

        If ``n`` argument is negative or omitted, read all data until end of
        file is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty
        string is returned when end of file is encountered immediately.
        """
        pos = self._buf.tell()
        end = self._buf.seek(0, SEEK_END)

        if n < 0:
            if not self._eof:
                self._buf.write(self._fin.read())
                self._eof = True
        else:
            req = pos + n - end

            if req > 0 and not self._eof: # need to grow
                bcount = _align_up(req, self._chunk_size)
                bytes  = self._fin.read(bcount)

                self._buf.write(bytes)
                self._eof = len(bytes) < bcount

        self._buf.seek(pos)

        return self._buf.read(n)

    def seek(self, offset, whence=SEEK_SET):

        if whence == SEEK_END:
            if not self._eof:
                self._buf.seek(0, SEEK_END)
                self._buf.write(self._fin.read())
                self._eof = True
            return self._buf.seek(offset, SEEK_END)

        return self._buf.seek(offset, whence)

    def close(self):
        self._fin.close()
        self._buf.close()
````

Usage example:

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://test/file.zip')

import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(BufferedRandomReader(req), 'r')

...
```